Laravel: file inside the array becomes empty when using file()
I have an array of files that being sent from request and the form element is has "enctype="multipart/form-data" also product_logo[] is the one that handles the file.
The issue is that when I try to loop inside the product logo. When I try to debug the $file it returns empty or when I also use hasFile() function it returns false.
// Loop through product_logo
foreach ($validated['product_logo'] as $key => $value) {
    dd($value, $validated['product_logo'], $request->hasFile($value));
    $file = $request->file($value);
    $path = $file->store('wl/product_logo', 'public');

    $wlConfigImage = WlConfigImage::create([
        'wl_config_id' => WlConfig::where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)->first()->id,
        'name'         => $value->getClientOriginalName(),
        'path'         => $path,
    ]);

    WlService::where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)
        ->where('accelerate_service_id', $key)
        ->update([
            'wl_config_images_id' => $wlConfigImage->id,
        ]);
}

Debugging result


hasFile() accepts the name of the sent variable, not the uploadedFile object

even if I used the hasFile(). $file shouldn't be empty because I have passed the uploadedFile object? The $file is still null when debugging

Looking at the dd() info, you don't need to use $request->file() since you've already have an instance of the UploadedFile. In this case, $request->file() would just return the same thing.
As mentioned in the comments, hasFile() (and file()) accept the name of the input, not the file itself. Passing the instance of the UploadedFile won't work as it's just using data_get() under the hood.
Looking at the code, I'm assuming you're using $request->validate(), so depending on your validation, this is all you would need to do:
foreach ($validated['product_logo'] as $key => $file) {

    $path = $file->store('wl/product_logo', 'public');

    $wlConfigImage = WlConfigImage::create([
        'wl_config_id' => WlConfig::where('user_id', Auth::id())->first()->id,
        'name'         => $file->getClientOriginalName(),
        'path'         => $path,
    ]);

    WlService::where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)
        ->where('accelerate_service_id', $key)
        ->update([
            'wl_config_images_id' => $wlConfigImage->id,
        ]);
}

If you do need to check if it is a file e.g. the field could be nullable, you could do something like:
foreach ($validated['product_logo'] as $key => $file) {
    if (!$request->hasFile('product_logo.'.$key)) { // or (!$file instanceof \Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile)
        continue;
    }
}

